# Row Rendering Event on Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

```
// Row Rendering event
public void Row_Rendering() {

    // Enter your code here 
}
```

Here is the condition I want to execute..

```
"SCHD TIME" - is the TIMESTAMP(value) from SQL

if (SCHD_TIME >= 15mins) {
    return 'background-color:red; color:#fff'
} else if (SCHD_TIME> 15mins <= 30mins) {
    return 'background-color:yellow; color:#000;'
} else if (SCHD_TIME> 30mins <= 2hours) {
    return 'background-color:green; color:#fff'
} else if (SCHD_TIME> 2hours) {
    return 'background-color:none';
}
```

or if there is an easier way of executing this on the server side please share thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rendering doesn't happen server-side. Any visual changes always happen client-side, though the info for those changes can be passed from the server side via a POST method or just do it all via client-side. The code isn't that complicated and could easily be achieved through javascript/jQuery. A good date format for javascript is [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/), lots of good time comparisons and parsing, almost on par with C# DateTime. As well in jQuery you can edit the background color of the table by either making classes like 'red', 'green', 'yellow' and use .addClass() and .removeClass() to change between them or else use .css('background-color', 'green'), ect, ect to change the color of the row.

Good Luck!